# c# Appium dont work cycle

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

Friends help with the cycle!
There is so much construction and its work very vell:

```
while (driver.FindElementsByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'text')]").Count==0){}
```

How can I instead of "text" to register the variable?
If I insert project.Variables ["test"]. Value or test, I get errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJOLJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBO6J.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the red squiggles, it should tell you what the issue is. Then you can google the error message and learn how to fix it.

The problem is that you have nested double quotes `"` so the first inner `"` is ending the string. Change it to

```
project.Variables['test'].value
```

and it should work. Note the `'` instead of `"` surrounding `test`.